# JQuery ready function resets page after document has loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load a div's html from a text file using jquery. I am currently calling my function in the document.ready. It works for a split second then the page resets back to the original html. Why does it not stay the way its loaded from the text file.

My Code is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>    
<script>
             $(document).ready(function(){  
             $("body").click(function(event){
                var data = CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData();
                $.post("save.php", { param: data } );       
            });
             var linkToTextFile = 'testFile.txt';
            $.get(linkToTextFile, function(data){
               $('div.content').html(data);
            }); 
           });
    </script>
```

It seems to have something to do with CKeditor. If I remove all of its references, it works fine.

Comment: what other javascript is on pagev ?

Comment: I have also tried `$("div.content").load("testFile.txt");`